# How to verify if jpg shows on page using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

Using python, selenium, and firefox. I am clicking a link on a homepage and it leads directly to a JPG file that loads. I just want to verify that the image loads. The HTML of the image is this:

```
<img src="https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Agency%20Documents/Organizational%20Chart.jpg" alt="https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Agency%20Documents/Organizational%20Chart.jpg">
```

I am trying to use xpath for locating the element:

```
def wait_for_element_visibility(self, waitTime, locatorMode, Locator):
     element = None
     if   locatorMode == LocatorMode.XPATH:
          element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, waitTime).\
                until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, Locator)))
     else:
         raise Exception("Unsupported locator strategy.")
     return element
```

Using this dictionary:

```
OrganizationalChartPageMap = dict(OrganizationalChartPictureXpath = "//img[contains(@src, 'Chart.jpg')]",                                 
)
```

This is the code I am running:

```
def _verify_page(self):
    try:
      self.wait_for_element_visibility(20, 
                                     "xpath", 
                                     OrganizationalChartPageMap['OrganizationalChartPictureXpath']
      )
    except:   
      raise IncorrectPageException
```

I get the incorrectpageexception thrown every time. Am I doing this all wrong? Is there a better way to verify images using selenium?

Edit : Here is the DOM of the elements :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending the `alt` value should work in xpath, would suggest you to change the dictionary to :

```
= dict(OrganizationalChartPictureXpath = "//img[@alt='https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Agency%20Documents/Organizational%20Chart.jpg' and contains(@src, 'Chart.jpg')]"
```

OR

alternatively use the full path to the image in the `src` as :

```
= dict(OrganizationalChartPictureXpath = "//img[@src='https://www.treasury.gov/about/organizational-structure/ig/Agency%20Documents/Organizational%20Chart.jpg']"
```

***Edit :***
According to the DOM shared in the image, you can also use the class of the `img` which would be a corresponding code into your project to this :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('shrinkToFit')
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried the full path using the src before and unfortunately didn't work. Just tried your first suggestion and also same thing unfortunately. It searches and evaluates OK in firebug/firepath via those xpath locator strategies. The element is found and highlighted, but for some reason won't run in the code. Frustrating as the solution must be a simple one! Tried both firefox and chrome. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are there any other methods I could try? I've tried a simple find element, wait for element to be visible, and wait for element to be clickable. Tried using xpath and css. Nothing is working. What other alternatives are there? Is there a way to verify the image without even clicking on the link? Or even downloading the image?

Comment: @Vince if you could share the html for the parent of the element, could be easier to access via other strategies.

Comment: @Vince : updated the details in the question, also updated my answer

Comment: Tried locating by class. Firepath finds it as expected, but it just won't resolve when running the code. Removing my incorrectpage exception just leads to a timeout exception. Can't seem it figure it out here-- maybe just an issue with this particular page? I've just settled with checking the link path for the correct file extension for now. It would be nice to figure out what's going on here though. Thanks for your help

Comment: Figured this out. The page was opening in a new window, which I had not even noticed all along... I used .switch_to_window() and got it working.